# be+verb or be+ to verb is right?

Tags: verbs

Here is a sentence:

[target sentence](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-upload-pdf-files-to-your-wordpress-site/)

[image]
First thing you need to do is install and activate the Google Doc Embedder plugin.

Maybe the formal format :
First thing you need to do is to install and to activate the Google Doc Embedder plugin.

be+verb or be+ to verb is right?

Comment: As I explained in my answer on the other question, *to* is optional here.  Usually it's required, but this case is special.  That's because the subject (*the first thing you need to do*) has a subordinate clause containing *do*, which makes *to* optional.  I would also add *the* to the beginning of your sentence (*the first thing*, not *first thing*).